# On the existence of a Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Consider a rational function $f(z)\in\mathbb{R}(z)$ with no poles/zeros on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\, |z|=1\}$. Does there always exist a Möbius transformation
$$
\rho\colon \overline{\mathbb{C}}\to \overline{\mathbb{C}}, \ \  z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \quad a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}, ad-bc\neq 0,
$$
such that the pole/zero at infinity of $f(z)$ (if present) is mapped to a finite point outside the unit circle and all the other finite poles/zeros of $f(z)$ inside (outside) the unit circle remain finite and inside (outside) the unit circle after the transformation?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; you can even additionally require that $\rho$ map the entire unit disk to itself.  Just note that for any point $p$ in the open unit disk, there is a Mobius tranformation $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(p)=0$ and $\sigma$ maps the unit disk to itself.  Now pick any $p$ such that $0<|p|<1$ and $1/p$ is not a root of $f$ and let $$\rho(z)=\frac{1}{\sigma(1/z)},$$ where $\sigma$ is as above.  Then $\rho$ maps the unit disk to itself since $\sigma$ does, so it preserves whether roots of $f$ are inside or outside the unit circle.  Also, $\rho(1/p)=\infty$, so neither $\infty$ nor any of the roots of $f$ map to $\infty$ under $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, is for instance $\rho(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-az}$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $|a|<1$, $1/a$ not a root of $f$, a valid transformation?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that should work.